# Why won't my saved home screen shortcuts open?

Tags: samsung, home-screen-shortcuts

Today, I turned on my Samsung Galaxy S8 and all the shortcuts I "saved to home page" won't open. The shortcuts are now gray on my home screen. When I click on one, an error pops up that says "App not found".

[image]

These aren't downloaded apps. These are websites and web pages I saved to the home screen for later reference. Newspaper articles, local cleaning services, stuff I "saved to home page".

Yesterday was the changeover from Samsung Cloud to Microsoft One Drive Cloud, (I think). Could this have something to do with it? I changed over to One Drive last week.

Any help would be appreciated.

Comment: Those links are connected to your web browser app (Samsung Internet or whatever web browser you used for creating the links). Warning: clearing the app data of that web browser will result in all links being deleted.

Comment: Thankyou Robert. I actually restarted my phone and they all just came back. So...problem solved! Thankyou for your reply though!!